# Woocommerce checkout field

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

is it possible to hide certain checkout filed in woo-commerce when user is logged in ? like i have a checkout field of Email address  i do not want my user to see this when the user is logged in  Your suggestion would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
   if(is_user_logged_in()){
      unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);
   }
return $fields;
}
```

Source : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/